# pass data from ajax success data to ejs templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I just started to use ejs. Now, I want to pass data gotten from ajax result to two different div in ejs.

I can pass to a single div but for multiple divs, what change do I need in my code?

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: serviceurl + 'Get',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({  "imagesrc":  imagesrc }),
      success: function (data) {
           var  property = JSON.parse(data.GetResult);
           $('.insideContent>').remove() ;                              
           $('.insideContent').addClass("insidecontentcss") ;  

           var str = $("#insidecontenttooldata").html();
           var data = { tooldata: property };
           var content = new EJS({ text: str }).render(data);
           $(".insideContent").html(content);

           var str1 = $("#well").html();
           var data1 = { tooldata: property };
           var content1 = new EJS({ text: str1 }).render(data);
           $(".well").html(content);
      }
```

and in ejs page i use two script like

```
 <script id="insidecontenttooldata" type="text/x-ejs-template">
         //// loop////
</script>
 <script id="well" type="text/x-ejs-template">
      ///loop///
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have error while targeting second template. Modify code as follows:

```
 var str1 = $("#well").html(); //id of template is 'well' and not the 'welldata'
 var data1 = { tooldata: property };
 var content1 = new EJS({ text: str1 }).render(data1);
 $(".well").html(content1);
```

Note: as suggested by @kristjan reinhold modified the code to use relative variables.

Comment: Should also use new EJS({ text: str1 })

Comment: ya try but not getting

Comment: ejs_production.js:1 an error shown in"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token catch"

Comment: seems like some issue with your second template code. please check it.

Comment: Omg, just copy the first working template and change variable names troughout second. xD

Comment: in template i try like "   <script id="welldata" type="text/x-ejs-template">

                   <%for(var i=0;i < tooldata.wellconfiguration.length;i++){%> 
                   <% debugger; %>
                      <div class="conductorHeading"><%= tooldata.well[i].tittle%>(<%= headvalue %>) </div>


          </script>

Comment: @manup - now you are saying id of template is `welldata` whereas in your question i can see it as `well`. Please tell us which is correct one.

Comment: try modifying `tooldata.well[i].tittle` to `tooldata.wellconfiguration[i].tittle`

Comment: thanks all. thats my templates mistake i correct it :)